# Android 12 is blocking the touches when using the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

Tags: android, android-studio, android-12

I am using `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />` to show a pop up which overlay over other apps but android 12 is blocking the touches .
As per the documentation it blocks the touch events
how can i allow touches on android 12 .

Here is the link for android 12 behavioural changes touch events
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all#untrusted-touch-events

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.input.InputManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;


public class FloatWidgetService extends Service {

    private WindowManager mWindowManager;
    private View mFloatingWidget;

    public FloatWidgetService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
        mFloatingWidget = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_floating_widget, null);
        mFloatingWidget.setFilterTouchesWhenObscured(true);
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;
        try {
            mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            mWindowManager.addView(mFloatingWidget, params);


            mFloatingWidget.findViewById(R.id.root_container).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                private int initialX;
                private int initialY;
                private float initialTouchX;
                private float initialTouchY;

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            initialX = params.x;
                            initialY = params.y;
                            initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                            initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                            return true;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            int Xdiff = (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                            int Ydiff = (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                            if (Xdiff < 10 && Ydiff < 10) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                                stopSelf();
                            }
                            return true;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                            params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                            mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatingWidget, params);
                            return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mFloatingWidget != null) mWindowManager.removeView(mFloatingWidget);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you link a DOC with info about blocking touches? some common "widgets" are using this perm and I've never noticed any click/touch problem with these

Comment: @snachmsm https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all#untrusted-touch-events

Comment: @snachmsm i added please check below

Comment: well, looks like you are using `FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE`, which isn't possible now with window created using `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission, I can understand intent of this decision, I doubt it can be now ommited

Comment: i am not using FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE , i am using using the permission SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

Comment: as above: I'm not facing this issue personally with `View`s drawn using `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`, in my apps and personal-use 3rd-party. good luck with tracking this out, imho you should post your configuration/code of your `Service`

Comment: @snachmsm added service code

Comment: at first: you said that you aren't using `FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE`, but I see it in your code when creating `new WindowManager.LayoutParams`... besides that you should use `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` on API26+ instead of (kind of hacky) `TYPE_PHONE`. e.g. `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26 ? WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE : WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY`

Comment: @snachmsm did that but still not enabling touches

Comment: sadly don't have any other clues... I've checked one of my apps, some old (26-28) targeting, but built with newest API31 and still working, configured like your code (also with `FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE`). my "floating widget" contains just some very simple layout, `LayoutParams` set for window have fixed size and I'm not intended to intercept any touch outside my widget

Comment: Has the phone user given your app permission to display over other apps? That is required (app info-> Display of other apps).

Comment: @Cheticamp already given

Comment: I have the same problem with Android 12 (API 31) and for some reason, this is not an issue with Android 13 (API 33).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for the window type:

```
val windowType: Int = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
} else {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT
}
```

See [TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY).

This is Kotlin, but you should be able to convert to Java easily.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible anymore. As stated in the docs, applications with window type:

TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY

Aren't trusted and therefore won't be excepted from this protection.

How ever, they do write this:

> Exceptions:
>
> Completely transparent windows. The alpha property is 0.0 for the
> window.

So you can try removing:

> PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT

and instead set a real color, but with 0 alpha, such as (#00XXXXXX)
might work but that's just a guess

Answer (score 0):

Setting the alpha window value fixed it for me

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
   windowParams.alpha = 0.8f;
}
```

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all#untrusted-touch-events-exceptions) are a bit confusing because they say the alpha value has to be zero but then they say the combined window opacity has to be less than or equal to the system's maximum obscuring opacity for touches, which for Android 12 is 0.8.

This is only required for Android 12 (API 31). I didn't need to set the opacity for Android 12L or 13.